# Geodesic and Local parameter

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose a surface $S$ If I have the coefficients from the first fundamental form, for a local parameter $X(u,v)$, equal $E=G=u$, $F=0$, where $u>0$. How to determine the geodesics of $S$ in the range of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geodesics are determined by these two differential equations:

$\ddot u +  \dot u^2 \Gamma_{11}^1 + 2\dot u \dot v \Gamma_{12}^1 + \dot v^2 \Gamma_{22}^1 = 0 $

and

$\ddot v +  \dot u^2 \Gamma_{11}^2 + 2\dot u \dot v \Gamma_{12}^2 + \dot v^2 \Gamma_{22}^2 = 0, $

and we know the values of $\Gamma_{i,j}^{k}$ in function of E,F and G. You cand find them in this image

[image]

So just replace the values and try to solve the equations.
Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I wasn’t be able to see the image.

Comment: I've edited it. Can you see it now? :)

Comment: Yes, ok. Thank you very much!